# Select multiple subfolders in one Finder windows

Tags: select, applescript, directory

In my applescript, I am trying to select all subfolders in selected folders. The script seems to successfully select the wanted subfolders, but the each them in multiple separate windows according to their parent folder. Is there a way to force them to be open in one window (as if you expand folders in list view and cmd click to select subfolders from multiple folders)?

Thanks,

Poon

Here is the code, just in case.

```
tell application "Finder"
set SelectedFolders to selection
set i to 1
set NewSelection to {}
repeat with aFolder in SelectedFolders
    repeat with bFolder in aFolder
        copy bFolder to the end of NewSelection
    end repeat
end repeat
select every item of NewSelection
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try "set selection" instead of "select". The front Finder window will have to be in list view and the appropriate folder will have to be expanded already. Basically if what you're trying to select is not visible in the front Finder window then it will not work.

```
set selection to NewSelection
```

I do not know of a way to expand a folder programatically. However you can ensure the Finder window is in list view using this...

```
set current view of Finder window 1 to list view
```

I think what you're trying to do will prove difficult. I couldn't get it to work consistently in my brief testing. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't rely on this...

```
tell application "Finder"
    set SelectedFolders to selection
    if SelectedFolders = {} then return

    set current view of Finder window 1 to list view
    my rightArrow()

    set NewSelection to {}
    repeat with aFolder in SelectedFolders
        set NewSelection to NewSelection & folders of aFolder
    end repeat

    if NewSelection ≠ {} then
        set selection to NewSelection
        my rightArrow()
    end if
end tell

on rightArrow()
    activate application "Finder"
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Finder"
            key code 124
        end tell
    end tell
end rightArrow
```